# How to set StartDate and FinishDate to todays date, and not a date range

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a script that currently pulls a selected date range of data, however I need to change it to simply take the current days data. Currently the script is as follows:

```
SET SiteID='1001'<br>
SET StartDate='2014-09-26'
SET FinishDate='2015-09-30'
SET OutputFolder=C:\Innovate
SET ScriptFile=InnovateSaffronNonVatable.sql
SET ServerInstance=(local)\SQLExpress
```

I have tried amending the StartDate and FinishDate as follows but the query doesn’t return any data.

```
SET StartDate= GetDate()
SET FinishDate= GetDate()
```

How do I amend this script to only take today's data, and not a date range?

Thank you in advance for your help. It is much appreciated.

Christopher.

Comment: Hi Chris, I am not entirely sure what you are asking here. Have you declared StartDate and FinishDate to 'DATE' datatype?

Answer (score 0):

`getdate()` returns the time (hours, minutes, etc) in addition to the date and in your case you don't want that.

Try:

```
SET StartDate= CAST(GETDATE() as DATE) --Today without time

SET FinishDate= CAST(GETDATE() as DATE) --Today without time
```

or

```
SET FinishDate= DATEADD(day,1,CAST(GETDATE() as DATE)) --Tomorrow
```

Answer (score 0):

FIRST DECLARE VARIABLES

THEN

SET ֲֲֲ@StartDate= GetDate()

SET @FinishDate= GetDate()

Answer (score 0):

```
SET StartDate=convert(date,getdate()) --Today without time
SET FinishDate=convert(date,getdate()+1) --Tomorrow without time
```